# Consecutive count by groups

Tags: r, count

How do you generate conditional cumulative counts, by groups?  Specifically, my data has columns:  Name of individual, date, month and temperature.  I want to generate a table that shows the number of consecutive days that temperature exceeded 38oC, for each individual within each month.

One answer explains how to do cumulative counts by groups (How to Perform Consecutive Counts of Column by Group Conditionally Upon Another Column), but I'm not sure how to add in the condition that I only want the cumulative count with the condition that temperature is greater than 38oC.

Here is what the original table looks like:

```
Individual name | Month | Date   | Temperature
Greg            | 1     | 2/1/16 | 26
Greg            | 1     | 3/1/16 | 25
Greg            | 1     | 4/1/16 | 39
Greg            | 1     | 5/1/16 | 39
Fred            | 1     | 2/1/16 | 40
Fred            | 1     | 3/1/16 | 41
Fred            | 1     | 4/1/16 | 41
Fred            | 1     | 5/1/16 | 41
```

This is what I want to generate:

```
Individual name | Month | Largest consecutive string of days >38oC
Greg            | 1     | 2
Fred            | 1     | 4
```

Comment: Also, I realise that there may be multiple strings of consecutive days >38oC (for an individual within a month), but I only need to know the greatest number of consecutive days where this condition is met.

Comment: Have a look at `?by` and `?rle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Individual_name', 'Month' and the run-length-id of logical vector (`Temperature > 31`), we get the `sum` of the logical vector, then grouped by 'Individual_name' and 'Month', get the `max` value of the summarised column ('V1') from the earlier step.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, sum(Temperature > 31), .(Individual_name, Month, grp=rleid(Temperature > 31))
      ][, .(LargestConsec = max(V1)), .(Individual_name, Month)]
#   Individual_name Month LargestConsec
#1:            Greg     1             2
#2:            Fred     1             4
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we create a function with `rle` by extracting the `lengths` based on the TRUE elements in 'values' (as we are doing the `rle` on a logical vector).  Grouped by the 'Individual_name' and 'Month', apply the function on 'Temperature' to get the `summarize`d count of largest consecutive groups.

```
f1 <- function(vec, thresh) {
    with(rle(vec > thresh), max(lengths[values]))
}

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Individual_name, Month) %>% 
    summarise(LargestConsec = f1(Temperature, 31))
#   Individual_name Month LargestConsec
#            <chr> <int>         <int>
#1            Fred     1             4
#2            Greg     1             2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Individual_name = c("Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
"Fred", "Fred", "Fred", "Fred"), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("2/1/16", "3/1/16", "4/1/16", "5/1/16", 
"2/1/16", "3/1/16", "4/1/16", "5/1/16"), Temperature = c(26L, 
25L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L)), .Names = c("Individual_name", 
"Month", "Date", "Temperature"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` option that doesn't require a function

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Individual_name, Month) %>%
  filter(Temperature>38 & lag(Temperature, n=1L)>38) %>%
  summarise(consecutive=n()+1)
```