# Generating a variable to count consecutive entries

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
df <- read.table(text="UTCDate  UTCTime   White   Black
    2018.01.01 03:49:40 JL  XN
    2018.01.01 03:52:01  XN JL
    2018.01.01 03:54:16 JL  XN
    2018.01.01 03:55:58  XN JL
    2018.01.01 03:57:59 JL  XN
    2018.01.01 04:00:27  XN JL
    2018.01.01 04:01:48 JL  XN
    2018.01.01 04:03:43  XN JL
    2018.01.01 04:06:12 JL  XN
    2018.01.01 09:21:16 JL  OC
    2018.01.01 09:22:28  OC JL
    2018.01.01 09:24:16 JL  OC
    2018.01.01 09:24:58  OC JL", header=T)
```

I am trying to create a column that tracks "consecutive games" where a consecutive game is defined as, say, any entry that is less than 10 minutes from the preceding entry. Here, consecutive game is defined from the perspective of some player (e.g. JL) so rows 1 through 9 would read (1:9) in consec_games column and rows 10 through 13 would be (1:4).

The column "consecutive_games" should only apply to a single player (e.g. JL). So it would be JL_consecutive_games.  This is a large dataset where multiple player may be playing others at the same time.  Therefore, the consecutive games column has to apply only to some pre-specified player (in this case, JL).

I have seen answers like this: [Consecutive count by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254014/consecutive-count-by-groups) which take advantage of the lag function, but I'm not sure how to apply a lag to this dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a convenience `data.table` function:

```
consecutive_plays <- function(df, player, date_var = "UTCDate", time_var = "UTCTime", white_var = "White", black_var = "Black", diff_time = 10, unit_time = "mins") {

  require(data.table)

  setDT(df)[, `:=` (TimeDimension = as.POSIXct(paste(get(date_var), get(time_var)), format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                    Player_Present = get(white_var) == player | get(black_var) == player)][
                      , time_diff := as.numeric(difftime(TimeDimension, shift(TimeDimension), units = unit_time) >= diff_time), by = .(Player_Present)][
                        is.na(time_diff), time_diff := 0][
                          get(white_var) == player | get(black_var) == player, paste0(player, "_consecutive_games") := seq_len(.N), by = .(Player_Present, cumsum(time_diff))][
                            , c("TimeDimension", "time_diff", "Player_Present") := NULL
                            ]

}
```

That you can call for any desired player:

```
df <- consecutive_plays(df, player = "JL")
```

And get the output with the corresponding column:

```
       UTCDate  UTCTime White Black JL_consecutive_games
 1: 2018.01.01 03:49:40    JL    XN                    1
 2: 2018.01.01 03:52:01    XN    JL                    2
 3: 2018.01.01 03:54:16    JL    XN                    3
 4: 2018.01.01 03:55:58    XN    JL                    4
 5: 2018.01.01 03:57:59    JL    XN                    5
 6: 2018.01.01 04:00:27    XN    JL                    6
 7: 2018.01.01 04:01:48    JL    XN                    7
 8: 2018.01.01 04:03:43    XN    JL                    8
 9: 2018.01.01 04:06:12    JL    XN                    9
10: 2018.01.01 09:21:16    JL    OC                    1
11: 2018.01.01 09:22:28    OC    JL                    2
12: 2018.01.01 09:24:16    JL    OC                    3
13: 2018.01.01 09:24:58    OC    JL                    4
```

If the player is not there for any of the games, the rows would be set to `NA`:

```
df <- consecutive_plays(df, player = "XN")

       UTCDate  UTCTime White Black JL_consecutive_games XN_consecutive_games
 1: 2018.01.01 03:49:40    JL    XN                    1                    1
 2: 2018.01.01 03:52:01    XN    JL                    2                    2
 3: 2018.01.01 03:54:16    JL    XN                    3                    3
 4: 2018.01.01 03:55:58    XN    JL                    4                    4
 5: 2018.01.01 03:57:59    JL    XN                    5                    5
 6: 2018.01.01 04:00:27    XN    JL                    6                    6
 7: 2018.01.01 04:01:48    JL    XN                    7                    7
 8: 2018.01.01 04:03:43    XN    JL                    8                    8
 9: 2018.01.01 04:06:12    JL    XN                    9                    9
10: 2018.01.01 09:21:16    JL    OC                    1                   NA
11: 2018.01.01 09:22:28    OC    JL                    2                   NA
12: 2018.01.01 09:24:16    JL    OC                    3                   NA
13: 2018.01.01 09:24:58    OC    JL                    4                   NA
```

It doesn't matter much how many players you have. You can easily quickly get the columns for all of them:

```
players <- unique(c(as.character(df$White), as.character(df$Black)))

for (player in players) { df <- consecutive_plays(df, player = player) }
```

Output:

```
       UTCDate  UTCTime White Black JL_consecutive_games XN_consecutive_games OC_consecutive_games
 1: 2018.01.01 03:49:40    JL    XN                    1                    1                   NA
 2: 2018.01.01 03:52:01    XN    JL                    2                    2                   NA
 3: 2018.01.01 03:54:16    JL    XN                    3                    3                   NA
 4: 2018.01.01 03:55:58    XN    JL                    4                    4                   NA
 5: 2018.01.01 03:57:59    JL    XN                    5                    5                   NA
 6: 2018.01.01 04:00:27    XN    JL                    6                    6                   NA
 7: 2018.01.01 04:01:48    JL    XN                    7                    7                   NA
 8: 2018.01.01 04:03:43    XN    JL                    8                    8                   NA
 9: 2018.01.01 04:06:12    JL    XN                    9                    9                   NA
10: 2018.01.01 09:21:16    JL    OC                    1                   NA                    1
11: 2018.01.01 09:22:28    OC    JL                    2                   NA                    2
12: 2018.01.01 09:24:16    JL    OC                    3                   NA                    3
13: 2018.01.01 09:24:58    OC    JL                    4                   NA                    4
```

Eventually, you can also then configure other parameters, e.g. if you would like to change the `diff_time` to more than 10 minutes, or if you would like to change the `unit_time` to `hours`, `days` or `weeks`, etc.

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely incredible.  Thanks a lot. I really need to invest the time to learn data.table -- it looks extremely powerful, but so much harder to read than dplyr.

Comment: Thanks, glad it's helpful! I find both have their pros and con; `dplyr` is certainly on the side of readability, sometimes it's also more practical (when it comes to `case_when` for instance), however due to speed I generally prefer `data.table` when writing functions or working with larger dataframes. P.S. There was a bug in the argument for desired time difference (it wouldn't work with anything else than 10 as it hasn't been transferred in the body of the function), I've fixed that in my edit, now it's called `diff_time`.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

In base R only.
First make a data/time object with the two separate columns `UTCDate` and `UTCTime`. Then use a `cumsum` trick to get the groups. Finally `ave` applies a function (`seq_along`) to each of the vectors defined by `d`.

```
UTC <- paste(df$UTCDate, df$UTCTime)
UTC <- as.POSIXct(UTC, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

d <- c(0, difftime(UTC[-1], UTC[-length(UTC)], units = "mins"))
d <- cumsum(d > 10)

ave(seq_len(nrow(df)), d, FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4

df$Games <- ave(seq_len(nrow(df)), d, FUN = seq_along)

rm(UTC, d)    # Tidy up
```

Comment: Does this handle the "perspective of some player" aspect properly? Tho I don't really grok what the OP wants when they say that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Good question. The example given, player `JL` is in *all* rows so I really don't know what the OP means by that and left it out.

Comment: What I meant is that the column "consecutive_games" should only apply to a single player (e.g. JL). So it would be JL_consecutive_games.  The values in this column would be different if it were from the perspective of another player (e.g. OB) if OB had been playing with some other player other than JL, and then immediately (within 10 minutes) began playing with JL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the tidyverse that gives you the result for all players:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

df %<>%           
  gather("color", "player", 3:4) %>%
  unite(datetime, 1:2) %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  mutate(name = player)

df$datetime %<>% parse_datetime("%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S")

nested <- df %>%
           mutate(cond = difftime(df$datetime, lag(df$datetime)) < 600) %>% 
           group_by(player) %>%
           nest()

get_cons <- function(df) {
  df$consecutive_games[1] <- 1
  for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    if(df$cond[i] == T) {
      df$consecutive_games[i] <- df$consecutive_games[i - 1] + 1
    }
    df$cond[i] <- 1
  }
  df %>%
    select(- cond)
}

options(tibble.print_max = Inf) # to show entire tibble

map_df(nested$data, get_cons)

# A tibble: 26 x 4
   datetime            color name  consecutive_games
   <dttm>              <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 2018-01-01 03:49:40 White JL                    1
 2 2018-01-01 03:52:01 Black JL                    2
 3 2018-01-01 03:54:16 White JL                    3
 4 2018-01-01 03:55:58 Black JL                    4
 5 2018-01-01 03:57:59 White JL                    5
 6 2018-01-01 04:00:27 Black JL                    6
 7 2018-01-01 04:01:48 White JL                    7
 8 2018-01-01 04:03:43 Black JL                    8
 9 2018-01-01 04:06:12 White JL                    9
10 2018-01-01 09:21:16 White JL                    1
11 2018-01-01 09:22:28 Black JL                    2
12 2018-01-01 09:24:16 White JL                    3
13 2018-01-01 09:24:58 Black JL                    4
14 2018-01-01 03:49:40 Black XN                    1
15 2018-01-01 03:52:01 White XN                    2
16 2018-01-01 03:54:16 Black XN                    3
17 2018-01-01 03:55:58 White XN                    4
18 2018-01-01 03:57:59 Black XN                    5
19 2018-01-01 04:00:27 White XN                    6
20 2018-01-01 04:01:48 Black XN                    7
21 2018-01-01 04:03:43 White XN                    8
22 2018-01-01 04:06:12 Black XN                    9
23 2018-01-01 09:21:16 Black OC                    1
24 2018-01-01 09:22:28 White OC                    2
25 2018-01-01 09:24:16 Black OC                    3
26 2018-01-01 09:24:58 White OC                    4
```

And if you prefer it in wide format:

```
map_df(nested$data, get_cons) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(id), funs(stringi::stri_pad_left(., width = 2, pad = "0"))) %>%
  spread(name, consecutive_games)

# A tibble: 26 x 6
   id  datetime            color    JL    OC    XN
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 01    2018-01-01 03:49:40 White     1    NA    NA
 2 02    2018-01-01 03:52:01 Black     2    NA    NA
 3 03    2018-01-01 03:54:16 White     3    NA    NA
 4 04    2018-01-01 03:55:58 Black     4    NA    NA
 5 05    2018-01-01 03:57:59 White     5    NA    NA
 6 06    2018-01-01 04:00:27 Black     6    NA    NA
 7 07    2018-01-01 04:01:48 White     7    NA    NA
 8 08    2018-01-01 04:03:43 Black     8    NA    NA
 9 09    2018-01-01 04:06:12 White     9    NA    NA
10 10    2018-01-01 09:21:16 White     1    NA    NA
11 11    2018-01-01 09:22:28 Black     2    NA    NA
12 12    2018-01-01 09:24:16 White     3    NA    NA
13 13    2018-01-01 09:24:58 Black     4    NA    NA
14 14    2018-01-01 03:49:40 Black    NA    NA     1
15 15    2018-01-01 03:52:01 White    NA    NA     2
16 16    2018-01-01 03:54:16 Black    NA    NA     3
17 17    2018-01-01 03:55:58 White    NA    NA     4
18 18    2018-01-01 03:57:59 Black    NA    NA     5
19 19    2018-01-01 04:00:27 White    NA    NA     6
20 20    2018-01-01 04:01:48 Black    NA    NA     7
21 21    2018-01-01 04:03:43 White    NA    NA     8
22 22    2018-01-01 04:06:12 Black    NA    NA     9
23 23    2018-01-01 09:21:16 Black    NA     1    NA
24 24    2018-01-01 09:22:28 White    NA     2    NA
25 25    2018-01-01 09:24:16 Black    NA     3    NA
26 26    2018-01-01 09:24:58 White    NA     4    NA
```

Comment: This is an extremely instructive and great answer, but I accepted argonaut because he was a bit faster, and it's a bit more flexible.  Thanks so much for showing me how it's done in dplyr... so much left to learn!